# JBoss7.1.1.Final persistence Issue

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, jsf-2, jboss7.x

I have configured my existing web application which was perfectly working in jboss6 into jboss7. But when I configure it to JBoss 7, I get this Exception, but I cannot find a solution to it. Is this a bug in JBoss7 or is there anything wrong in my configuration?

**JBoss7 console:**

```
Calling "C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================


  JBoss Bootstrap Environment


  JBOSS_HOME: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final


  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\java


  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.prefe
rIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml


===============================================================================


13:19:59,358 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
13:19:59,525 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
13:19:59,593 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
13:20:00,820 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
13:20:00,820 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
13:20:00,833 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
13:20:00,841 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
13:20:00,865 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
13:20:00,906 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.0)
13:20:00,944 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
13:20:00,945 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
13:20:00,975 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
13:20:00,967 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
13:20:01,033 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
13:20:01,076 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
13:20:01,152 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
13:20:01,166 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
13:20:01,193 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
13:20:01,432 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
13:20:01,478 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
13:20:01,804 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
13:20:01,805 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
13:20:01,808 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
13:20:01,826 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015014: Re-attempting failed deployment myweb.war
13:20:01,926 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/MywebDS]
13:20:01,956 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "myweb.war"
13:20:04,847 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/myweb.war/WEB-INF/lib/com.springsource.javax
.mail-1.4.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
13:20:05,100 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider:org.apache.catalina.util.DefaultA
nnotationProcessor' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
13:20:05,104 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider:org.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.
InjectionCollection' for service type 'com.sun.faces.spi.injectionprovider'
13:20:05,111 INFO  [org.jboss.as.pojo] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017000: Found legacy bean/pojo namespace: urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0 - might be missing some xml features (potential exceptions).
13:20:05,297 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for MywebPU
13:20:06,135 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'myweb.war#MywebPU'
13:20:06,261 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
13:20:06,266 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
13:20:06,268 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
13:20:06,269 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
13:20:06,285 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-1) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: MywebPU
        ...]
13:20:06,331 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean in Module "deployment.myweb.war:main" from Service Modu
le Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/QuartzJobBean (Module "deployment.myweb.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getPackagesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:171)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:489) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:851) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:596) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/quartz/Job
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.quartz.Job from [Module "deployment.myweb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        ... 42 more


13:20:06,445 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class com.myweb.security.util.schedule.OrderExpireSchedule in Module "deployment.myweb.war:main" from Servi
ce Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/myweb/security/util/schedule/OrderExpireSchedule (Module "deployment.myweb.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getPackagesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:171)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:489) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:851) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:596) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/QuartzJobBean
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean from [Module "deployment.myweb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        ... 26 more


13:20:06,535 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."myweb.war#MywebPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException i
n service jboss.persistenceunit."myweb.war#MywebPU": Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: vfs:/C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/myweb.war/WEB-INF/classes/
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:596)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS011431: Could not load entity class 'com.myweb.security.util.schedule.OrderExpireSchedule' with PersistenceUnitInfo.getClassLoader()
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getPackagesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:489)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:851)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myweb.security.util.schedule.OrderExpireSchedule from [Module "deployment.myweb.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.HibernateAnnotationScanner.getPackagesInJar(HibernateAnnotationScanner.java:171)
        ... 11 more


13:20:06,605 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
13:20:06,607 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 7526ms - Started 313 of 552 services (161 services failed or missing depe
ndencies, 77 services are passive or on-demand)
13:20:06,811 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "myweb.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jbo
ss.persistenceunit.\"myweb.war#MywebPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"myweb.war#MywebPU\": Failed to start service"}}
13:20:07,164 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment myweb.war in 352ms
13:20:07,166 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."myweb.war#MywebPU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."myweb.war
#MywebPU": Failed to start service


13:20:07,171 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" =>
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"myweb.war#MywebPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"myweb.war#MywebPU\"
: Failed to start service"}}}}
```

My `persistence.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
          <persistence-unit name="MywebPU" transaction-type="JTA">
                    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
                    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MywebDS</jta-data-source>

                    <class>com.myweb.entity.Account</class>
                    <class>com.myweb.entity.Users</class>
                    <class>com.myweb.entity.Authorities</class>
                    <class>com.myweb.entity.Country</class>
                    <class>com.myweb.entity.ExpiredOrders</class>

                    <properties>
                              <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
                              <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="5" />
                              <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
                              <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
                              <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
                              <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
                              <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
                    </properties>

          </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your stack trace it seems that JBoss cannot find the quartz library. Try to include it with your war file, because it is not included by default in JBoss 7.

Answer (score 0):

Based On your exception, Did you miss to configure `com.myweb.security.util.schedule.OrderExpireSchedule` in `persistence.xml`?

Comment: this one was a unused class thats y its not in persistence.xml so i removed it, thanks for mentioning